# How to share source code between host and guest VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, network-shares

I am a web developer. My computer runs Windows 10 LTSB in an AD domain. I develop source code on my local machine. I would like to boot a VM that runs an Apache/SQL/etc server to run my code on. The VM must be Windows, I could use Windows 7 or Windows 10 or perhaps Windows Server (2012 probably). I need to make my PHP source code on my host available to the server on VM. How can I do this?  I could use Hyper-V or VMWare to manage the VM. Neither seem to have good options for sharing files between the host and guest. They both recommend using regular windows file sharing.

I think windows file sharing will be problematic? I'd have to create a local user on the host machine, then share my source code. Then on the VM, map a network drive to my host. I'm not sure I can create a local user on my host, since I am on a domain? That might be locked down. I looked into running an NFS server on my Windows 10 LTSB host, but this doesn't seem to be a viable option. I am hoping there is a better option.

I love how in Docker you can just tell it to make C:\inetpub on the host available as C:\inetpub on the VM. This is exactly what I would like to do.

A DFS setup might be another option? But then I'd use up 2x the amount of space on my hard drive, and I don't know if the sync would be fast enough.

Comment: VMware, Hyper-V, and VirtualBox all support shared directories

Comment: You probably miss this ([for virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)) You can share host's folder directly to guest. Just mount it in guest and use

Comment: @Ramhound do you have any links to reference? I've done a lot of Googling and all I can find on VMWare and Hyper-V is that you have to use regular Windows network file sharing. Update - Yes VMware has a feature to share a folder from the host, but it just shows up as a network folder on the guest. I guess that may be an option, I think it would not require authentication so it might work!

Comment: @Alex thanks for that link, I am looking into using VirtualBox.

Comment: No problem, make sure to install guests additions on the guest's side, otherwise shared vbox folder won't work

Comment: @RyanStille - VirtualBox also has shared directories.\

Answer (score 0):

With [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)! You can share your host files in the VM at /vagrant or \vagrant. It uses [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It sets up a driver to access the host files automatically. It also offers rsync:// protocol, SAMBA/SMB, and nfs:// protocol.

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, the best option is to put your code on a flash drive, and then connect that flash drive to the virtual machine.  That way, you can still easily edit your source code from the host machine, and then also easily run it from the virtual machine.